# Can query name variable be parameterized in Python API?

Tags: python

The following API function works. But I would like to parameterize the query name so that I don't have to use if...else. Instead, I would like to be able to take the parameter from the query URL, concatenate it to the query name variable and execute the query.

I would like to be able to stick "`qry_`+ `<reportId>`" and use it as the query name variables like `qry_R01`, `qry_R02`, or `qry_R03`. Is it possible?

```py
def get_report():
    reportId = request.args.get('reportId', '')`

    qry_R01 = """
            SELECT
                column1,
                column2,
                column3,
            FROM
                table1
    """

    qry_R02 = """
            SELECT
                column1,
                column2,
                column3,
            FROM
                table2
    """

    qry_R03 = """
            SELECT
                column1,
                column2,
                column3,
            FROM
                table3
    """

    db = OracleDB('DB_RPT')

    if (rptId == 'R01'):
        db.cursor.execute(qry_R01,
    )

    elif (rptId == 'R02'):
        db.cursor.execute(qry_R02,
    )

    elif (rptId == 'R03'):
        db.cursor.execute(qry_R03,
    )


    json_data = db.render_json_data('json_arr')

    db.connection.close()

    return json_data
```

Comment: You should use a Prepared Statement. I don't know which database library you're using, but look in its documentation for Prepared Statements, and use them. _Never substitute a string directly into a database query_. It is technically possible, but you should never do it because that's how SQL injection happens and then someone using your program can kill your database.

Answer (score 0):

It seems what you need in this case is to map from `reportId` to the table, the rest of the query is identical. The below solutions uses a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) and [str.format()](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#format):

```py
def get_report():
    reportId = request.args.get('reportId', '')

    # this maps ours possible report IDs to their relevant query suffixes
    reportTableMap = {
        'R01': 'table1',
        'R02': 'table2',
        'R03': 'table3',
    }

    # ensure this report ID is valid, else we'll end up with a KeyError later on
    if reportId not in reportTableMap:
        return 'Error: invalid report'
    
    baseQuery = '''
    SELECT
        column1,
        column2,
        column3,
    FROM {table}
    '''

    db = OracleDB('DB_RPT')

    db.cursor.execute(baseQuery.format(table=reportTableMap[reportId]))

    json_data = db.render_json_data('json_arr')

    db.connection.close()

    return json_data
```

This solution only works for fairly simple cases, though, and does risk leaving open a SQL injection attack. A better solution would be to use [prepared statements](https://pynative.com/python-mysql-execute-parameterized-query-using-prepared-statement/) but the exact code to do that depends on the database driver being used.

Comment: Michoel, thanks for your response. It would have been the best answer if my goal is to substitute the name of the table in the query.
But, my goal is to substitute part of the query name (In your example: baseQuery). Say, I had 3 queries - baseQueryA, baseQueryB, baseQueryC and conditionally, I would like to execute one or other query base on the user input (A, B or C). 
Thank you again.